# how to pop a transient dialog after an save action?

Tags: iphone, dialog

Hi just want to know how to add a transient dialog saying that action is performed.

like when user clicks save and you pop up saved and the window disappears itself in less than a second?

thanks advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an action sheet like so:

```
/*  present a dialog  */
-(void)showDialog {
    loadingActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something was saved!" delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [loadingActionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5f target:self selector:@selector(closeActionSheet:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


/*  close the actionsheet  */
-(void)closeActionSheet:(id)sender {
    [loadingActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Define `UIActionSheet *loadingActionSheet;` in your header, and use `@property` & `@synthesize` .

You will also need to implement `UIActionSheetDelegate` in your header.